# child form minimize goes to task bar

Tags: c#

I have an MDI form which displays a treeView control, when the user clicks on the tree node child form, it opens:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    frmPartMaster frm = new frmPartMaster();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Here `frm` is displaying the backside of the tree control but I want it to show form in front of parent, not back. So I changed the code to:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    frmPartMaster frm = new frmPartMaster();
    frm.Show(this);
}
```

Here the child form is displayed in front of the tree, but when I minimize the child form it goes to task bar.How do I get it to go to the left corner of of parent form?

Comment: Note when you indent lines four spaces, the lines are [formatted as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the parent form's `IsMdiContainer` property to `true`. Then while opening the child form add the following code:

```
frm.MdiParent = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MDI? Then it won't come to Task bar. You can set the ShowInTaskbar option to false, which will not display for in Taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Real MDI child forms do not minimize to the taskbar. Therefore I can only conclude that you are not using an MDI child form and that your solution is to start doing so.